# jpa join on unrelated columns with equality

Tags: sql, jpa

I am trying to achieve this query with jpa:

```
select * from A a join B b on a.columnA = b.columnB;
```

Why is this not working?

```
  CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
  CriteriaQuery<Tuple> selectQuery = cb.createQuery(Tuple.class);
  Root<A> a = selectQuery.from(A.class);
  Join<A, B> b = a.join("columnA");
  b.on(b.get("columnB"));
```

Error thrown:

```
Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [columnB] on this ManagedType [unknown]
```

Adding Class Entity definitions:

```
class A {

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverride(name = "something", column = @Column(name = "columnA"))
  private UUIDT<A> columnA;

}

class B {

  @Embedded
  @AttributeOverride(name = "something", column = @Column(name = "columnB"))
  private UUIDT<InputFeature> columnA;

}
```

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing the entities themselves (classes `A` and `B`), but remember that in JPA you have to use Java property names, not db column names!

Comment: does this help? also added to original question:
class A {

  Embedded
  AttributeOverride(name = "something", column = Column(name = "columnA"))
  private UUIDT<A> columnA;

}

class B {

  Embedded
  AttributeOverride(name = "something", column = Column(name = "columnB"))
  private UUIDT<InputFeature> columnA;

}

Comment: Ok, that makes sense; please include the definition of `UUIDT` in the question. But in any case I *guess* that `UUIDT` has only 1 attribute named `something`. The JPQL query should be like: `SELECT ... FROM A a JOIN B b ON a.columnA.something = b.columnA.something`. I cannot interpret this to criteria API right now, but notice I am using the Java field names (both `columnA` according to the question) and then *dot* the property of the `UUIDT` object. You probably need JPA 2.1 for `JOIN ... ON`. And I am not sure if it is even possible in criteria API!